# Determine the order of $Z_8/ \langle [3] \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

Determine the order of $Z_8/ \langle [3] \rangle$

Ok, I feel like I'm missing something very simple. The order of $Z_8$ is 8. The order of $\langle [3] \rangle$ is 3. But 8/3 does not divide evenly. What am I missing?

Comment: In the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_8^*$, the order of $3$ is $2$; in the additive group $\mathbb Z_8$, it’s $8$

Comment: The order of $\mathbb Z_8^*$ is $4$, by the way (the order of the additive group $\Bbb Z_8$ is $8$, as you indicated)

Comment: Please clarify whether you're referring to the additive group $\Bbb Z_8$ (which has order $8$) or the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_8^*$ of invertible elements, which has order $4$.

Comment: @RobertShore I wrote the question exactly as it is. I have no further information on it

Comment: Presumably $\Bbb Z_n$ is defined in your book or other source material.  Does that help us know whether we're referring to the additive or multiplicative group?

Answer (score 2):

I think $[3]$ might actually refer to the set of elements of $\mathbb Z_8$ *generated by* $3$. If this is the case, then the order of $[3]$ is equal to $2$, since $3^2 \equiv 1\bmod 8$, implying that $[3]=\{1,3\}$.